# Conditional on the value of a sibling node

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to come up with an xpath that will return node SES05 only when it is in the same LOOPSES as a CRS01 node with value 'R'. In the following XML it would return "SPRING" but not "FALL".

```
<LOOPSES>
    <SES>
        <SES05>FALL</SES05>
    </SES>
    <LOOPCRS>
        <CRS>
            <CRS01>T</CRS01>
        </CRS>
    </LOOPCRS>
</LOOPSES>
<LOOPSES>
    <SES>
        <SES05>SPRING</SES05>
    </SES>
    <LOOPCRS>
        <CRS>
            <CRS01>R</CRS01>
        </CRS>
    </LOOPCRS>
</LOOPSES>
```

I tried out this xpath:

```
LOOPSES/SES/SES05[.//LOOPCRS/CRS/CRS01="R")]
```

but it doesn't return anything. Is what I'm asking possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate is on the element `SES05` which doesn't have any `LOOPCRS` descendants. Put the predicate on `LOOPSES` instead.

Try something like this:

```
LOOPSES[LOOPCRS/CRS/CRS01='R']/SES/SES05
```